# Short if-else logic

Tags: php, if-statement

Why this

```
$count = 0;
   echo $count === 0
    ? 'zero'
    : $count === 1
     ? 'one'
     : 'more';
```

echoes 1? Shouldn't it echo zero?

Comment: Please don't abuse the ternary operator this way. This is so much less clear than a simple `if/else` structure, and anybody maintaining your code (including yourself three months from now) is going to hate you for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utilize parenthesis!

```
echo ($count === 0 ? 'zero' :($count === 1 ? 'one': 'more') );
```

The reason why your version echoes 'one' is because php thinks the 1st `?` is part of the statement therefore if `$count` is equal to zero do the last possible thing (last `?`) which is `'one'`

read up on [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: I read the question. and i gave an answer why it echoes one. and i gave a version which echoes what he really wants

Answer (score 0):

While this is a pretty short list of values, you could alternatively use a map:

```
$map = array("zero", "one", "more");
echo $map[min($count,2)];     // trick: 2 becomes max value via min()
```